# Passing Value from Spinner setonItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I am trying to get the position of a spinner item and pass it into another method. To achieve this I have declared a spinner in MainActivity and set onItemSelectedListener method(to get the position based on user click). Now I want to pass the value from the onItemselectedListener method to another method getItem(). But the value recieved at getItem() is always null. I have attached my code for further reference.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    String[]array={"I","Me","Myself"};
    String abc;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinnerAdapter adapter=new spinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.addAll(array);
        adapter.add("Select Here");
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());

       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           abc= String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

           }
       });

        getitem();
    }

public void getitem()
{
    Log.e("MSG",abc);
}


    }
```

Comment: Well, the abc variable will get value **when** the user select one item from the spinner.
In this code snippet, you call your `getitem()` method from `onCreate()`. So your method will only called when the `onCreate()` also run. 
Try move the `getitem()` call after the variable initialization. Similar to this: `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               abc= String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
               getitem();
           }`

Answer (score 0):

From Android dev [website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html):

### Responding to User Selections

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
...

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

From `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)` you can then get the string value and pass it to another activity if you wish.